# generate characters dynamically except other characters and removing duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A I have below data set.

```
A1 :TR029A/TR029B/TR045A/TR045B
A2 :TR028A/TR028B/TR052A
A3 :TR035A/TR035B
A4 : TR045B/TR065A
```

are there any way to generate column B data as below.

```
B1: TR029/TR045
B2: TR028/TR052
B3: TR035
B4: TR045/TR065
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you will have to create your excel function with VBA if you want this level of control

- press ALT+F11 to go to VBA view
- right click VBAProject > Insert > Module
- a window will open in which you can type VBA code

copy this VBA code into the window that opened to create the new function GenChars that you want:

```
Option Explicit

Function GenChars(value As String)
    ' an array of individual elements that were delemited by "/"
    Dim xs() As String
    xs = Split(value, "/")

    ' remove the last character from each element or replace it with @ if it would be a duplicate
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(xs) To UBound(xs)
        Dim x As String
        x = xs(i)
        x = Left$(x, Len(x) - 1) ' remove last char
        If ArrayContains(xs, x) Then x = "@" ' replace duplicate elements with @
        xs(i) = x
    Next i

    Dim value2 As String
    ' new value with duplicates
    value2 = Join(xs, "/") ' put the elements back into 1 value
    ' remove @ that was used instead of duplicates
    value2 = Replace(value2, "/@", "") ' remove occurrences of /@ (1st element is never duplicate)

    GenChars = value2
End Function

' whether array xs contains element y
Function ArrayContains(xs As Variant, y As Variant) As Boolean
    ArrayContains = False

    Dim x As Variant
    For Each x In xs
        If x = y Then ArrayContains = True
    Next x
End Function
```

- press ALT+F11 again to go back to normal view
- to use it, for example go into cell B1 and type:
  =GenChars(A1)

Comment: hi symboint,please tell me how to give the cell range which colum data should remove and generate to which column

Comment: can you please share the excel file

Comment: @SandaruwanWeerasinghe installed as per the instructions and works perfect.

Comment: can you share the excel via google drive.i just copied.in which column should i enter the data and to which column it will generate.how can i chage the colum later

Comment: @SandaruwanWeerasinghe yes, of course i tested the code. the function works on individual cells. after putting "=GenChars(A1)" in cell B1, you can you can copy B1 to the cells below to create a column

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this pic as proof that symbiont's code works :

[image]

Install instructions faultless and clear, good job.

Added that same function in col F :

[image]

Comment: @symbiont just showing it worked, feel a bit guilty - that vote should be on yours...

Comment: are there any way to ask directly from you regarding vba  questions here?Im new here .

Comment: You need to post clear questions, there are many on here who are **so** much better than me in vba - and if you have a look at the questions I have posted you will see. But you will find lots of useful vba stuff on here if you look

Comment: @SolarMike i voted it up myself because i considered it helpful so no worries :)